# Not getting back enough columns

Tags: sql-server, join

My query is as follows:

```
select [Transaction].id, 
       [User].name, 
       EventType.EnglishDescription
  from [Transaction] 
  join [User] on [Transaction].userid = [User].id 
  join EventType on EventType.id = [Transaction].EventType
```

I'm expecting to get back Transaction.id, User.name and EventType.EnglishDescription in the columns, however, I'm only getting back an id column.

When I leave out Transaction.id from the select, I get both the name and the EnglishDescription.

Comment: What you mean you get back the columns but the values are `NULL` or wrong somehow - or the columns simply don't appear at all?

Comment: The columns simply don't appear at all.

Comment: How are you running this? In Management Studio? Is it in a View, Procedure, or Function?

Comment: As a stored procedure against a mdf file. If needed I can give you the table layout as a sql file.

Comment: Can you post what you are actually seeing as a result?  Sounds to me like the response text is getting truncated somehow.

Comment: Against an mdf file. So I guess that is SQL Express? Can you reproduce the behaviour when you run it in Management Studio? If so can you get the Actual Execution Plan? BTW: Details of how to connect to a user instance SQL express instance in SSMS are here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/11/22/connecting-to-sql-express-user-instances-in-management-studio.aspx. The option to get the Actual Execution Plan when you execute the query is on the query menu.